# Transformation Pentaho Kettle getting Stuck

Tags: cassandra, etl, pentaho

I was created my transformation using pentaho data integration to read data from Cassandra then copy data to other database. Then I created bat script to call my transformation using kitchen and the script was called by windows scheduler every 5 minutes. The script was fine and running smoothly, but after few hours(7 hours) got problem, the transformation stuck and couldn't finish the job. I was checked the log, the last step was ***"Dispatching started for transformation"***. The transformation can't start again until I killed the OSGI Service listened port.

Is it some problem with PDI or because of cassandra database it self? How to resolve my problem?

Comment: How you are executing your batch file? i mean using which scheduler?

Comment: Ya, I created bat file and call it using scheduler.  Then I tried to increase cpu resource and memory the problem not stopped again. But then the other issue coming in after 1 month run smoothly without error. In the log file showed the error "ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container for bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.console"

Comment: One of the issue can be with CPU memory. If the process is continuously running then at certain point of time it runs out of memory, other issue can be cassandra timeout,try to increase the timeout.

Comment: I tried to deleted everything in folder Cache "..\pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342\data-integration\system\karaf\caches" then the errors were gone. Any solution to avoid that error without delete the caches manually?